# How to pass different types as struct{} to function in GoLang?

Tags: go, struct, types, type-conversion, parameter-passing

I want to write a function that takes different struct-types as 1 parameter. Also, I have to be sure, that in these structs is an `Id` field. So I want a function like this:

```
MyFunction(object *struct{ Id int })
```

I tried it with passing the struct as a `*struct{ Id int }` and an `interface{}` parameter.

For example, I have these 2 struct-types:

```
type TableOne struct {
    Id   int
    name string
    date string
}

type TableTwo struct {
    Id      int
    address string
    athome  bool
}
```

To save them in the database (using `reflection`) I have the following function:

```
func SaveMyTables(tablename string, obj *struct{ Id int }) {
    // ... Some code here

    if obj.Id != 0 {
        // ... Some code here
    }

    // ... Some code here
}
```

I call the function like this:

```
obj := &TableTwo{
    Id: 5
    address: "some address"
    athome: false
}

myPackage.Save("addresses", obj).
```

But I get this error:

> cannot use obj (type *mytables.TableTwo) as type *struct { Id int } in argument to myPackage.Save

Comment: Go is a strictly-typed language. If you specify a struct type for an argument, that is the type that must be passed, *exactly*.

Comment: @Adrian, i understand. So there is no other way than to implenent the exact same function multiple times, only with an other agrument type? That's exactly what I wanted to prevent.

Comment: You said you tried passing the value in an `interface{}`. That is the correct method, what didn't work?

Comment: @JimB i have to be sure that the struct has a `Id int` variable, because @
`if obj.Id != 0 {`
Golang requires to _know_ that the variable is there. Also `interface{ Id int }` does not work.

Comment: You can't. There is no way to have a contract on fields. An interface offers a contract on *behavior* (as it should). The design needs to be corrected from the ground up.

Comment: Ok. There seems to be a way if completly handle the struct with reflection. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to write a function that takes different struct-types as 1 parameter. Also, I have to get sure, that in these struct is an `Id` field.

As of the current version of Go, you cannot do this. The only way Go supports passing multiple argument types to a single parameter is through the use of interfaces, and interfaces can only specify method sets, not fields.

(Go 2 plans to add generics, and this may be possible then. However, there's no concrete timeline for when that will be available.)

Comment: go generics are now available, but I still don't know how to do this